# How to redirect (header location) to an html file?

Tags: php

So I'm running a registration/login system, MySQL included, in php.

For testing purposes, after a successful login, I redirect the user to an index.php, that states that the user is logged in, and gives him the option to log out.

Meanwhile, I made an actual html page I plan on using, so instead of the header('location: index.php') in my login.php file, I simply added index.html.

Except, this happens.

**Not Found**

**The requested URL /registration/index.html was not found on this server.**

Any idea as for why this happens? I made sure all of the files I need are in the folder itself, index.php shares the same location as index.html.

Am I missing something obvious?

```
// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: index.html');
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says it's trying to redirect to `/registration/index.html`. Did you want to redirect to that page or to '/index.html'?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to redirect to that page.

Answer (score 3):

Overall you have more important issues than a redirect problem. You will help yourself out if you create a config file that you include at the top of each base page. Also, employing some functions will keep your script human-readable, I have added a few examples. Don't use `md5()` for passwords, it's already been *"figured out"*, so-to-speak, therefore easily crackable. You want to use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` and if those are not in your PHP version *(you should be upgrading to a version that has it if possible)* then use a bcrypt compatible library. Also, use parameterized values in your sql, the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is not good enough. Finally, I would switch to the OOP version of mysqli, it is easier to use, in my opinion.

**/config.php**

```
<?php
# Create a constant for your domain, this makes redirect super easy!
define('BASE_URL', 'http://www.example.com');
# Create a constant for your root folder (this config should be in the root)
define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);
# Create a function dir
define('FUNCTIONS', ROOT_DIR.'/functions');
# Add session to this page
session_start();
# Add our session var creator
include_once(FUNCTIONS.'/setSession.php');
# Add our get session function (use to retrieve session values)
include_once(FUNCTIONS.'/getSession.php');
# Add our message creator (set all messages via this)
include_once(FUNCTIONS.'/setMessage.php');
# Include our redirect function
include_once(FUNCTIONS.'/redirect.php');
```

**/functions/validate.php**

```
<?php
function validate($username, $password, $con, &$errors)
{
    # Prepare the statement
    $query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
    # Bind the parameter
    $query->bind_param('s', $username);
    # Execute the query
    $query->execute();
    # Fetch the row
    $result = $query->fetch_assoc();
    # Stop if there is no username matching
    if(empty($result['password'])) {
        $errors[] = "Invalid Username or Password.";
        return false;
    }
    # See if the password matches
    return (password_verify($password, $result['password']))? $result : false;
}
```

**/functions/redirect.php**

```
<?php
function redirect($path)
{
    header("Location: {$path}");
    exit;
}
```

**/functions/setSession.php**

```
<?php
function setSession($key, $value, $multi = false)
{
    if($multi)
        $_SESSION[$key][] = $value;
    else
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
```

**/functions/getSession.php**

```
<?php
function getSession($key = false, $clear = false)
{
    if(!empty($key)) {
        $value = (isset($_SESSION[$key]))? $_SESSION[$key] : false;
        if(isset($_SESSION[$key]) && $clear) {
            unset($_SESSION[$key]);
        }
        return value;
    }

    return $_SESSION;
}
```

**/functions/setMessage.php**

```
<?php
# It's easier to store in the same key all the time, then you can save multiple
# and retrieve them all at one time with implode()
function setMessage($msg, $key = 'general')
{
    setSession($key, $msg, true);
}
```

**/functions/getMessage.php**

```
<?php
function getMessage($key = 'general', $clear = true)
{
    return getSession($key, $clear);
}
```

**/login.php**

```
<?php
# add the config
include_once(__DIR__.'/config.php');
# Preset the errors array
$errors = [];
# Check for login
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    # Set all variables to match keys
    $username = (isset($_POST['username']))? trim($_POST['username']) : false;
    $password = (isset($_POST['password']))? trim($_POST['password']) : false;
    # See if empty
    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        # Add the validate function
        include_once(FUNCTIONS.'/validate.php');
        # Remember, we want to use the OOP version of $db
        $results = validate($username, $password, $db, $errors);
        # If the user array is set
        if (!empty($results)) {
            # May as well store all the user data
            setSession('user', $results);
            # Store username (or use the one in the user array instead)
            setSession('username', $username);
            # Save the success message
            setMessage('You are now logged in', 'success');
            # Put in full domain using our constant
            redirect(BASE_URL.'/index.html');
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but this is kind of a presentation only system, I don't really need it to be "secure". It's also run locally, I don't have a domain. I'll see what I can do with this, thanks.

Comment: You can likely still do a local host domain and if security is not required, then may as well not even convert to md5(), it’s only slightly better than plaintext.