# Is there a better way to write this login script?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Is there a better way to write this code to where I can pull data from my `id`, `firstname` and `lastname` columns during login?

```
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    if (empty($email)) {
        array_push($errors, "EMAIL is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: index.php');
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `md5()` is not a safe to use for passwords. You should use `password_hash()` & `password_verify()`

Comment: You should use prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php it will help protect you better than mysqli_real_escape_string against SQL injections.

Comment: This is the third time in about a week I have seen this code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53918626/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934098/error-bcrypt-login-fail-after-successfull-database-register#comment94713042_53934098 is this a tutorial or something?